# React Transition Group with Tailwind CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, css-transitions, tailwind-css, react-transition-group

I am trying to implement carousel using `<TransitionGroup>`, `<CSSTransition` which comes with `react-transition-group`. I am making use of CSS framework `Tailwind CSS`. But, while working with `<CSSTransition />`, we have to import css.

component.js

```
<TransitionGroup>
    {itemArray.map((item, idx) => (
        <CSSTransition
            timeout={350}
            classNames={direction}
            key={Math.random() + idx}>
            <div className="relative mt-8 max-w-full inline-flex">
              {item?.item}
            </div>
        </CSSTransition>
    ))}
</TransitionGroup>
```

style.css

```
.right-enter{ /* style */ }
.left-enter { /* style */ }
```

Is there any way transitions with `react-transition-group` can be handled using Tailwind CSS without needing to import css.

I tried to implement the same using `<Transition>`, but if classes are updated on life-cycles (`onEnter`, `onEntered`) , it will throw `too many re-renders` error.

Comment: Hi Sujay, not answering your question directly here, but for TailwindCSS you might want to try HeadlessUI. It's their implementation of animated UI components and it includes a [Transition module](https://headlessui.dev/react/transition).

Answer (score 3):

You can use this approach by [**React Transition Group**](http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/css-transition):

```
classNames={{
 appear: 'your tailwindcss codes',
 appearActive: 'your tailwindcss codes',
 appearDone: 'your tailwindcss codes',
 enter: 'your tailwindcss codes',
 enterActive: 'your tailwindcss codes',
 enterDone: 'your tailwindcss codes',
 exit: 'your tailwindcss codes',
 exitActive: 'your tailwindcss codes',
 exitDone: 'your tailwindcss codes',
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

To extend on @Saman answer, here's a simple FadeIn on appearance/enter and FadeOut for exit using TailwindCSS classes:

```
const classNames = {
  appear: "opacity-0",
  appearActive: "transition-opacity duration-300 opacity-100",
  enter: "opacity-0",
  enterActive: "transition-opacity duration-300 opacity-100",
  // exit: "opacity-100",  // this breaks the exit transition
  exitActive: "transition-opacity duration-200 opacity-0",
};
```

Comment: Please note that `react-transition-group` combines enter and exit classes after the delay. Your example would only work if `opacity-0` is defined as a final class in CSS. Since it cannot be guaranteed, I would use sth different, for example `!important` - `!opacity-0`.